# @Value is not taking value from specified @PropertySource when two properties files have same key

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, spring-profiles

I am trying to create two classes to fetch configuration values from two different properties file (`application-e1.properties` and `application-e2.properties`).

`application-e1.properties` =>

```
param=e1Test
```

`application-e2.properties` =>

```
param=e2Test
```

I have created 2 classes `EmployeeDev` and `EmployeeTest` to read from respective files:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application-e1.properties")
public class EmployeeDev {

    @Value("${param}")
    String param;

    public String getParam() {
        return param;
    }

    public void setParam(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application-e2.properties")
public class EmployeeTest {

    @Value("${param}")
    String param;

    public String getParam() {
        return param;
    }

    public void setParam(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    }
}
```

Whenever I call `EmployeeDev` or `EmployeeTest`, it is always returning param value as `e2Test`.

I am trying to create the configuration of 2 profiles at a time here.
Can anyone help me through this?

Comment: Couldnt you prefix your properties keys ? Like `test.param` and `dev.param` ? Since you load both properties files, Spring will collapse them and overwrite your config.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Spring's Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) this is what `@PropertySource` does:

> Annotation providing a convenient and declarative mechanism for adding a PropertySource to Spring's Environment. To be used in conjunction with @Configuration classes.

> In certain situations, it may not be possible or practical to tightly control property source ordering when using @PropertySource annotations. For example, if the @Configuration classes above were registered via component-scanning, the ordering is difficult to predict. In such cases — and if overriding is important — it is recommended that the user fall back to using the programmatic PropertySource API.

So all this annotation does is adding a specific property source to the existing environment.

What your code does is, it combines the two sources **application-e1.properties** and **application-e2.properties** by merging the properties into one environment, while the later properties overide the prior ones. You now have an `Environment` where **param=e2Test** is set. Adding already existing property sources are not predictably in terms of overriding.

What you should do is having different `Profiles` which have their properties set in their related property files and then activate the profiles you need. If you wanna set differents specific params for different usecases within one and the same profile you have to name them separately.